# What is ELF file?

Tags: elf

We're writing an emulator project for college and we have to use ELF file as an input, but we're not quite sure what does ELF file looks like. It should contain certain operations which we can execute (and all of them should be represented binary), but does it contain something else? Or is the first line first operation we are executing?
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Your favourite search engine would be a much better resource for your enquries.  Any answers you might get will probably be either links to resources you can find by searching or regurgitations of (parts of) such resources.  Voting to close.

Comment: This is easily looked up. ELF format is well documented.

Answer (score 4):

ELF is the [Executable and Linkable Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linking_Format), the file format for executables, libraries and object files used by most operating systems that aren't Windows or OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Event logs can be found at: %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs. Copy a small file to a desktop and rename the extension to ".dat" instead of ".evtx" and view the file using a text viewer like notepad++.

The first line shows that the file follows the ElfFile format.